# keeping a class added after postback with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
function pageLoaded() {

    $(".panel-dividers").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("collapsed");
            return false;
        });
});
```

How do I keep the class collapsed in the div after postback with jquery?

Comment: cookies, postback in hidden data field etc, the same way you are persisting other user data when posting to the server. This will depend with your server side implementation (asp?, php?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring a server side indicator into the jquery and test for it.

```
function pageLoaded() {

    var my_server_side_indicator_of_collapsed_state = <INSERT SERVER SIDE STUFF> (eg. <?php echo my_var; ?>)

    if( my_server_side_indicator_of_collapsed_state === TRUE ){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("collapsed");
    }

    $(".panel-dividers").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("collapsed");
            return false;
        });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use an AJAX approach and return an indicator in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that because jQuery is client side and it doesn't remember any changes made in DOM before page refresh.

When page is refreshed it loads the entire DOM fresh again.

You can consider using [**JSON for postback**](http://softwarecycling.com/post/2861344855/json-postbacks-with-mvc)

And there is another way using [**DOM Storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) as suggested by @Jitendra

Comment: @user1177860 Somehow try not to refresh the page. You can consider using JSON

Comment: You can pass your class in query string and get it again or you can store in browser's cookie. You can also save it into session. Or simply try not to reload the whole page, use ajax to interact with server. It all depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies or store the toggle on the server so it can be re-rendered as a preference.

Easiest (and with as little interference with regards to a per-user setting) would be to use cookies. Using [`$.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and adding it to your click code to store the preference (then on a page load recall those preferences and show.hide accordingly) would be a good bet--**however** that requires the headings have some unique ID to them otherwise it's an all-or-nothing kind of setting.

To further clarify, if you have 3 headings all shown at page load and you click hide on one of them the cookie is presumably set to hide. Next page load all elements are hidden because there was nothing saying that the [first|second|third] element was the one clicked.

### Update

If you don't have IDs on the panels and either can't make any or don't want to, you can use the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/QLdDW/1/) to make it work. one caveat, however, is that it works as long as the order of the panels don't change (since the IDs are generated by jQuery on load not a fixed ID given by the server).

```
$('.panel-divider').each(function(id){
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        className = 'collapsed',
        cookieName = [className,id].join('-');
    
    if ($.cookie(cookieName) === className){
        $parent.addClass(className);
    }
    
    $this.on('click',function(){
        $parent.toggleClass(className);
        if ($parent.hasClass(className)){
            $.cookie(cookieName, className);
        }else{
            $.removeCookie(cookieName);
        }
    });
});
```

Again, [here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QLdDW/1/) (When jsFiddle loads click the gray headings to toggle the panel. Then, hit the <kbd>Run</kbd> button again and the page will reload the saved settings. Lather, Rinse, Repeat.